# Why aren't my changes to the scheduler in Laravel being reflected?

Tags: php, laravel, scheduler

I am working on updating the schedule function in my Kernel.php file. I have versions of this file locally and on a production instance. There is a `$schedule->call` function that was set to run 4 different functions every 5 minutes. One of those functions is outdated and shouldn't be run anymore, so I commented it out locally and in the production instance.

I have a database table that logs the name of each function each time they are ran. When I checked my table, I saw that all 4 functions are still being run every 5 minutes. When I ran `php artisan: schedule:run`, the log showed only the 3 desired functions. But that's only when I run it manually, and it had no change on what was being run automatically.

I have seen stuff about cron, but I am confused if this is something I need to enter on the command line or if it might be some file I need to set up to get my scheduler to properly update?

This is what I am referring to that I saw on the Laravel documentation site:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Any advice or direction would be much appreciated:

Answer (score 1):

I've been bitten by this more often than I care to admit.  It is potentially a caching issues.  Run the following:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan queue:restart
```

The queue is the one that gets me every time.